# Django - order a model by the number of many to many relationships it has

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

let's say users can join many hubs and hubs can have many users - our typical many to many relationship. Now, I would like to filter hubs by the number of users it has. something like:

```
Hub.objects.all().order_by("users_count")
```

anything like so?

Answer (score 0):

```
hubs = Hub.objects.annotate(num_users=Count('user')).order_by('num_users')
```

It's explained in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by